# Custom hotkey even with unfocused form

Tags: vb.net, timer, focus, keydown, keycode

I am having a bit problems trying this. I must admit that I am still novice programming. Well, I managed for do this in this way (VB.NET):

`Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown Then
            MORE IRRELEVANT CODE HERE
        End If
    End Sub`

But with this way, even if it work, it dont let me customice the key shortcut (only Control, shift and others).

I did this too for try differents things:

`Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = GlobalVariables.own_key Then
           MORE IRRELEVANT CODE HERE 
        End If
    End Sub`

I give value to GlobalVariables.own_key from other button. This work perfectly, but only if program have the focus.

So... With the first code program work even if it haven't the focus but only with few keys... And with the second it let me use any key, but don't work if it haven't the focus.

I tryed understand the "keyboard hook" but I must admit that I didn't understad it and couldn't manage for work any of them.

Using VB.net 2012.

Really thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be an answer you like but it is the answer. In **.NET**, you cannot get notification of keys when your application does not have focus and you cannot get mouse events outside your applications windows.  If you *looked into* the "Keyboard Hook", you should have read that little important fact regarding VB.

[Global hooks are not supported in the .NET Framework](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319524)

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. It explain why "keyboard hooks" didn't work for me. But a question... I managed for get notifications keys while programs wasn't focus, just can't customice the key (the first example).

Comment: You might be able to find other keys WHILE they are pressed using your timer and My.Computer.Keyboard... code but it will not be reliable. This how often your timer would need to run to capture the fact a regular key is pressed as I type this comment.

Comment: Good point. I found those issues already time to time. Thanks so much for all answers.